# How to redirect old url alias to new url alias?

Tags: uri

Is there any way to redirect old URL alias to the new URL alias?

I want example.com/good-news to redirect to example.com/good-news-index, automatically.

Comment: Will Domain name be same for both url or different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [redirect](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) module to redirect url from "old url" to "new url".

> This module allows you to specify a redirect from one path to another
>   path or an external URL

There is also [global redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module which provide the same functionality.

> - Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if    it is not being used.
> - Checks the current URL for a trailing slash, removes it if present    and repeats check 1 with the new request.
> - Checks if the current URL is the same as the site_frontpage and    redirects to the frontpage if there is a match.
> - Checks if the Clean URLs feature is enabled and then checks the    current URL is being accessed using the clean method rather than the
>     'unclean' method.
> - Checks access to the URL. If the user does not have access to the    path, then no redirects are done. This helps avoid exposing private
>     aliased node's.
> - Make sure the case of the URL being accessed is the same as the one    set by the author/administrator. For example, if you set the alias
>     "articles/cake-making" to node/123, then the user can access the
>     alias with any combination of case.
> - Most of the above options are configurable in the settings page. In    Drupal 5 you can access this after enabling the globalredirect_admin
>     module. In Drupal 6, the settings page is bundled into the module

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 6 their is one more module [Path redirect](https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect), which adds one more option "Create a new alias. Redirect from old alias." in URL alias-> Automated alias setting -> General setting.

If this option is set, then whenever alias is changed/updated this module will redirect from old alias to new alias.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this should work with pathauto end redirect(check "Automatically create redirects when URL aliases are changed."). 
The Path redirect module name becomes [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect)